# Canonical ensemble to quantum system

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Any ideas to start the solution of the following problem?

Suppose that, by a suitable external mechanical or electrical arrangement, the energy of the heat reservoir could be increased by $nE$ whenever the reservoir passed to the subsystem the quantum of energy $E$.

Let $n$ be some numerical factor, positive or negative. Show that the canonical ensemble for such a subsystem is given by

$ \rho(E) \propto  e^{-(1-n)E/\tau} $

where $\tau$ is the temperature that characterizes each part of the system when thermal contact is assumed. Some measures must be taken to keep the whole system at a constant temperature if the process continues for a long time.

Any help would be welcome.